# Relative Entropy - Help please

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, entropy

I'm a bit stuck evaluating the relative entropy $\int_{}^{} f(\textbf{x}) \log \left(\tfrac{f(\textbf{x})}{g(\textbf{x})} \right) \mathrm{d}\textbf{x}$ (where f and g are two densities) in the case given below and I would appreciate someone's help:

$X_{1}$ has pdf N($\mu_{1}$,$\sigma^{2}$) and  $X_{2}$ has pdf N($\mu_{2}$,$\sigma^{2}$)

Comment: are you evaluating Gaussian? Is this hat Np means?

Comment: yes Gaussian, they are both Normally distributed where p is the dimension

Answer (score 0):

If $f_1$ is the $N(\mu_1,\Sigma_1)$ and $f_2$ is the $N(\mu_2,\Sigma_2)$ pdf, note that
$f_i (x) = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{p/2} |\Sigma_i|^{1/2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_i)^T \Sigma_i^{-1} (x-\mu_i)}$.

Now, $D(f_1 || f_2) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^p} f_1 (x) \log \frac{f_2}{f_1}(x) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^p} f_1(x) \left(\log \frac{|\Sigma_1|}{|\Sigma_2|} -(x-\mu_1)^T \Sigma_1^{-1} (x-\mu_1) +(x-\mu_2)^T \Sigma_2^{-1} (x-\mu_2) \right)$

Multiply this out to get terms of the form constants (i.e. don't contain $x$), $x^T v$, $v^T x$ and $x^T \Sigma_i x$ [all times $f_1$] in the integrand.

You'll get a bunch of terms which are of the form $\int x^T v f_1(x)$ for a vector $v$ (or $\int v^T x f_1(x)$ -- $v$ will depend typically on $\mu_i$ and $\Sigma_i^{-1}$. These will simply be $\mu_1^T v$ or $v^T \mu_1$ by linearity of expectation. Note that $\mu_i^T \Sigma_i^{-1} \mu_i$ is a constant as is $log \frac{|\Sigma_1|}{|\Sigma_2|} $ so you can pull those out and use the fact that $\int f_1 = 1$ to handle those terms.

The remaining terms $\int x^T \Sigma_i^{-1} x f_1(x) = E_1 [ x^T \Sigma_i^{-1} x] $ are the problem. Here, the trace permutation trick is useful. Note that $x^T \Sigma_i^{-1} x = tr(x^T \Sigma_i^{-1} x) = tr(x x^T \Sigma_i^{-1})$. Thus,  $E_1 [ x^T \Sigma_i^{-1} x] = E_1[tr(x^T \Sigma_i^{-1} x)] = E_1[tr(x x^T \Sigma_i^{-1})] = tr(E_1[x x^T] \Sigma_i^{-1}) = tr( (\Sigma_1 + \mu_1 \mu_1^T) \Sigma_i^{-1})$ by linearity of expectation and definition of covariance matrix.

Comment: I don't understand why $x^{T}$ $\Sigma^{-1}$ $\textbf{x}$ = tr($x^{T}$ $\Sigma^{-1}$ $\textbf{x}$). Thank you otherwise.

Comment: $x^T \Sigma^{-1} x$ is a scalar, so its trace is itself. Then, you're just using the fact that $tr(ABC) = tr(CAB)$.

Comment: But if $x^{T}$ $\Sigma^{-1}$ $\textbf{x}$ is a scalar, why is it automatically called the trace?

Comment: The trace of a scalar is itself. This follows from the definition of trace. This is something I noticed which makes the computation easy.

Comment: I believe you missed out a power of $\tfrac{1}{2}$ on the power of the determinant of covariance matrix and a factor of $\tfrac{1}{2}$ on the exp. term on the first line pdf which makes the relative entropy integral sightly different.

Comment: Indeed, I did. It has been corrected (though, conveniently, the errors were in such a way that you just calculated twice the relative entropy).